# Cordova android app over 2GB not for Google Play Store

Tags: android, cordova, html5-video, visual-studio-cordova

I cant seem to create a cordova app that is over 2GB in size.  Its going to be an app that plays locally stored video files.  I have them in the assets folder videos/myvideofile.mp4.  myvideofile.mp4 is less than 2GB in size, but multiple videos exist.

When I build, it fails with

```
 Zip add failed (-2147483648)
```

This seems to be related to Android\android-sdk\build-tools\24.0.2\aapt.exe.  My best guess is that it is related to this link and aapt.exe uses fseek which is limited to under 2GB. 
[AAPT: Zip add failed for assets larger than 2 GB](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75701)

I know I can add files to an SD card and read them from there, but I want to have all the files packaged inside the apk.  I am NOT going to be using the Google Play Store for distribution, so how can I get past this 2GB limitation on build?  My target api is 22.  If I have under 2GB in assets, it will build. I am using cordova CLI 6.3 via latest visual studio 2015 community

Comment: AFAIK this is not a tools limitation, but an Android limitation on the maximum APK size. See [comment #2 on the issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75701#c2).

Comment: I assume that it uses 32 bit calculations, so it maxes at MAX_INT, which is 2147483647, bytes in size